# WinForm : Application built using .net Framework 1.1

Tags: .net, winforms, frameworks

I have one application built using .Net Framework 1.1 and .net framework 4.0 already installed on client machine so does microsoft provides backward compatibility or do i still need to install .net Framewok 1.1 on client machine

Comment: I am getting given assembly name or code base is invalid error.

Answer (score 0):

> The .NET Framework 4 is backward-compatible with applications that
>   were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5. In
>   other words, applications and components built with previous versions
>   of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.100).aspx

Edit: You must check the migration issues and changes that might affect your application.